# difference between "++value" in this two example

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#define LOG(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl
void increment(int value)
{
    ++value;
    
}
int main()
{
    int a = 6;
    increment(a);
    LOG(a);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I press F11 and debug into the function of "increment".The parameter of function equal to 6.But why the "value++"doesn't work .I know it is called "pass by value",but I think local value should change in the function of body.

```
#include<iostream>
    #define LOG(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl
    void increment(int& value)
    {
        ++value;
        
    }
    int main()
    {
        int a = 6;
        increment(a);
        LOG(a);
        std::cin.get();
    }
```

here I pass by reference and the value plus one. Is that the reason the compiler can not get the address of "++value",so it will be discarded,sorry for the fist submit.

Comment: Because it is passed by value and not by reference. A copy is sent, modified to 7 and destroyed upon return. Not the actual object in main was modified.

Comment: I only see one example.

Comment: Tony ,I agree with you ,no better explanation

Comment: Tannous,if I pass by reference,you can see it in the next example . In the second situation ,Does the   "++value"  mean the address or value change?

Comment: @herring Value change, references are not pointers so there is no address to change. I'm afraid I not sure what you mean by `the compiler can not get the address of "++value"` You are misunderstanding something there but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @john  Beacause it is passed by reference,so we can find the address of "++value" in the second example. And we can only find the value in the first example. So, I want to express that.

Comment: In the first example, `increment` has its own `value` distinct from `a` in the caller `main`.  In the second example, `increment` has `value` which is an *alias* to `a` -- they are one-and-the-same.  (I'm trying to use vernacular terminology, not C++ language standard terminology.)

Comment: `because it is passed by reference, so we can find the address of "++value"` If you want to find the address of something you need to use the address-of operator `&`, so `&value` or `&++value` but the latter only works because prefix `++` returns a reference, not because `value` was passed by reference.